# using predefined class name String in my project

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I have the below code which throws the error given below. when the 'String[] args' is replaced with 'java.lang.String[] args' it doesn't throw error and runs method s1.method1().

Problem: why is the local String given preference over java.lang.String ?
according delegation model the Bootstrap class loader gets preference and java.lang.String loaded before the Test class is loaded. Am I missing something here. please point me to any reference for this behavior.

Test.java:

```
package diff;
class String {

    public void method1(){
    System.out.println("in my method");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s1 = new String();
        s1.method1();
    }
}
```

Error: Main method not found in class diff.Test, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Problem: why is the local String given preference over java.lang.String ?*

The local [name **masks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking) the one in `java.lang`. The `java.lang` package is implicitly imported by the compiler for every program, however you can't use `java.lang.String` as `String` because you **masked** the name `String`. As you noted, you can use `java.lang.String` **or** rename your `String` class (in short, don't add custom classes that conflict with class names from `java.lang`). This is not a class-loader issue, as after compilation all classes are fully qualified in the byte code.

Comment: one question. since the class names are fully qualified during compile time itself, the java.lang.String and local String class are considered different and both gets loaded. so for Example if I manage to create another java.lang.String Class I will be able to verify the class loader deligation?. my actual target was to check the class loader deligation/loading. please let me know if my understanding is right

Comment: You cannot replace `java.lang.String` - it is a final class and you would break significant parts of the JVM which rely on internal `String`(s).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make a distinction between types and *names*. You have created a class named `diff.String`, which does not collide with `java.lang.String`. The class loader delegation is irrelevant here; it’s not even possible to define a conflicting `java.lang.String` class, as names starting with `java.` are reserved.

When the simple name `String` gets resolved, local scopes have precedence. By the way, this happens at compile-time, which is another reason why class loaders are not relevant here. There is another precedence rule, variable > class > package, which allows the following weird code:

```
Integer String = 42;
String Integer = ""+String.intValue();
System.out.println(Integer);
```

The first statement declares a variable named `String` of type `Integer`. In the second statement, the first “`String`” gets resolved to a type, as a variable is not allowed at this position, whereas for the second occurrence of the name, in `String.intValue()`, the variable `String` takes precedence. Likewise, in the third statement, `Integer` gets resolved to the variable `Integer`.

Generally, programmers should follow the convention to let only class names start with an uppercase letter, which significantly reduces the need to know these rules.

The takeaway is, not every occurrence of the simple name `String` implies a reference to the type `java.lang.String`, it’s not even guaranteed to refer to a type. The context matters.